# postfix: maildir access problem; did I lose mail?

Tags: postfix

I found a few hundred of the following errors in my syslog following some configuration changes:

```
warning: maildir access problem for UID/GID=5000/5000: 
create maildir file /home/vmail/domain/account1
/tmp/1273028517.P14666.domain.com: Permission denied
```

I made a temporary fix for now (the ole' standby, chmod 777), but I would like to know if this is a permanent error (lost mail) or if these are retried/requeued.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **think** it is a 4xx situation, not 5xx; the Postfix log should display the result code sent to the remote MTA

Comment: Is there a way to map that maildir id (1273028517.P14666) to a queue id in the postfix log?

Comment: Don't know, you probably better ask in postfix-users mailing list: http://www.postfix.org/lists.html